# Kernel launch is out of resources

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm trying to implement the kernel bellow

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import numba
from numba import jit, cuda, float64, float32
from timeit import default_timer as timer

stream = cuda.stream()

cxmag = np.array([0,-1,0,0,1,0,0],dtype = np.float32);
cymag = np.array([0,0,-1,0,0,1,0],dtype = np.float32);
czmag = np.array([0,0,0,-1,0,0,1],dtype = np.float32);
cmag = np.array([cxmag,cymag,czmag]);

@cuda.jit
def inducedforce_gpu(u,B,gin,cmag,Fmag):
    nx, ny, nz = u.shape[1:];
    
    C = float32(0.5);
    nulb = float32(0.0032);
    etamag = nulb;
    omegamag = float32(1.)/(float32(4.)*etamag+ float32(0.5));
    k = omegamag/(C**2);

    
    l, k, j = cuda.grid(3)
    if (j < nx) & (k < ny) & (l < nz):
        Fmag[0,j,k,l] = float32(0.)
        Fmag[1,j,k,l] = float32(0.)
        Fmag[2,j,k,l] = float32(0.)
        UB = u[0,j,k,l]*B[0,j,k,l] + u[1,j,k,l]*B[1,j,k,l] + u[2,j,k,l]*B[2,j,k,l];
        BB = B[0,j,k,l]*B[0,j,k,l] + B[1,j,k,l]*B[1,j,k,l] + B[2,j,k,l]*B[2,j,k,l];
        
        for i in range(7):
            CmagB = cmag[0][i]*B[0,j,k,l] + cmag[1][i]*B[1,j,k,l] + cmag[2][i]*B[2,j,k,l];
            Bgin = B[0,j,k,l]*gin[0,i,j,k,l] + B[1,j,k,l]*gin[1,i,j,k,l] + B[2,j,k,l]*gin[2,i,j,k,l];
            
            Fmag[0,j,k,l] =  Fmag[0,j,k,l] - k*( (BB*u[0,j,k,l] - UB*B[0,j,k,l])/float32(3.5) +
                                                CmagB*gin[0,i,j,k,l] - Bgin*cmag[0][i] );
            
            Fmag[1,j,k,l] =  Fmag[1,j,k,l] - k*( (BB*u[1,j,k,l] - UB*B[1,j,k,l])/float32(3.5) +
                                                CmagB*gin[1,i,j,k,l] - Bgin*cmag[1][i] );
            
            Fmag[2,j,k,l] =  Fmag[2,j,k,l] - k*( (BB*u[2,j,k,l] - UB*B[2,j,k,l])/float32(3.5) +
                                                CmagB*gin[2,i,j,k,l] - Bgin*cmag[2][i] );
```

My kernel execution is

```
u = array(random.randint(10, size=(3,nx,ny,nz)),dtype = np.float32)
B = array(random.randint(10, size=(3,nx,ny,nz)),dtype = np.float32)
gin = array(random.randint(10, size=(3,7,nx,ny,nz)),dtype = np.float32)

u_device = cuda.to_device(u, stream = stream)
B_device = cuda.to_device(B, stream = stream)
gin_device = cuda.to_device(gin, stream = stream)
cmag_device = cuda.to_device(cmag, stream = stream)

Fmag_device = cuda.device_array(shape=(3,nx,ny,nz,), dtype=np.float32, stream = stream)

threadsperblock = (4, 16, 16)
blockspergrid_x = math.ceil(nz / threadsperblock[0]);
blockspergrid_y = math.ceil(ny / threadsperblock[2])
blockspergrid_z = math.ceil(nx / threadsperblock[1])
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y, blockspergrid_z)

inducedforce_gpu[blockspergrid, threadsperblock,stream](u_device,B_device,gin_device,cmag_device,Fmag_device)
cuda.synchronize()

s = timer()

inducedforce_gpu[blockspergrid, threadsperblock,stream](u_device,B_device,gin_device,cmag_device,Fmag_device)

cuda.synchronize()

gpu_time = timer() - s

print(gpu_time)
```

but I'm getting the error

> CudaAPIError: [701] Call to cuLaunchKernel results in CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

does anyone has an idea of why this is happening? I search for some errors like this, but I couldn't find out by myself. Actually at the first time I get the error, the Kernel was bigger because I was doing actually the same calculation a lot of times, and this version has some registers to deal with that, but even so, that didn't worked.

Comment: You are probably running out of registers. Try reducing your block size to a smaller multiple of 32

Comment: thanks @talonmies that solved my problem.